# Why do older airplanes have the wing curved upward like a 787?

Tags: commercial-aviation

I was just wondering one day about because the 787 uses a wing flex to reduce wing tip vortex, but back in World War 2 they didn't know about wing tip vortex, so then why would it be curved upwards?

[image: B-29 Bomber 3-view]

You can see in the middle picture the wing is curved upwards. I see this on a lot of commercial airplanes too like the Boeing 737

Comment: It's not curved, it's just a dihedral angle for stability.

Comment: @fooot that's about actual flex, this one is about dihedral.

Comment: @Federico It's not clear what is meant by "curved wing", and the 787 is much more notable for wing flex than dihedral.

Comment: @fooot I agree, but don't get thrown off course by the wrong assuptions behind the question: 787's wing flex is not there for reducing the wingtip vortex.

Comment: What is it there for?

Comment: @Federico Exactly, the linked question explains the reason for that, which seems to be at the basis of this question.

Comment: @Ethan the question linked in my first comment explains the reason and consequences of the wing flex.

Comment: The newest edit changed `Curved wing` to `wing flex`, so I think this can now be safely closed on @fooot's duplicate identification.

Comment: @Federico Actually doing a little research and the wing flex of the 787 reduces the strength of wing tip vortex to prove you wrong just look up wingtip device on wiki and raked wing tip is there and it acts just like a winglet

Comment: raked wingtip is not wingflex

Comment: Sorry meant rake wingtip

Comment: so you did not prove me wrong.

Comment: @Federico the raked wingtip actually reduce the vortex affect by 5.5% instead of a winglet which reduces it 3 to 4%. I know its off topic but its a fact.

Comment: and neither of those are "wing flex".

Comment: nope I really got my words confused

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are confusing 2 concepts here, dihedral and winglets. What you are showing in the picture is [dihedral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_(aeronautics)), which is not a curvature but an angle positive from the horizontal. This angle helps improve lateral (roll) stability in flight. This is nothing new, almost all commercial jets have dihedral. Winglets improve efficiency. A Boeing 787 has both.

Comment: The raked wingtips on the 787 aren't really winglets but they have the same function.

Comment: Yeah winglets are there to reduce wing tip vortex and the 787 has a different system than winglets to reduce wing tip vortex by having the wing curving upwards decreasing the strength of the vortex. The 787 has no winglet

Comment: The original poster is not referencing winglets in their post, or a wing rake.  They are referencing that the wings on a 787 are very flexible and bend upward noticeably during flight.  That's what he's confusing with the dihedral design.  It's flexibility v. structured angle.

Comment: I do actually @PeterKämpf as I don't agree on your interpretation of the question.